# HikariCP lost connections

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jtds, hikaricp

I've got an older using:

- Spring MVC (4.0.6.RELEASE)
- Spring data jpa (1.7.0.RELEASE)
- JDBC (1.3.1)
- Hikari (2.5.1)

  we're noticing connections that leave the pool and *never* comeback.  I have leaked connection logging enabled and we're trying to figure out why these connections never come back to the pool.  In the meantime, is there any sort of way to tell Hikari to abandon/replace a connection?  It seems like the call that's eating the connection is a simple JPA "findOne(UUID)" lookup.

thanks for any help

EDIT

```
2017-02-24 15:12:12,328 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - nGenDbPool - configuration:
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension.............false
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................true
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - catalog.........................null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery............."SELECT 1"
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout...............30000
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSource......................null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName.............null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,332 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,333 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - driverClassName................."net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................600000
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailFast..........true
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl........................."jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://my-server/myDB;appName={context_info};prepareSQL=0;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false"
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........5000
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................40
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................40
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - poolName........................"nGenDbPool"
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - readOnly........................false
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - registerMbeans..................false
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutorService........null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - threadFactory...................null
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation............"TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED"
2017-02-24 15:12:12,334 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - username........................"myLogin"
2017-02-24 15:12:12,335 | DEBUG | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout...............5000
2017-02-24 15:12:12,336 | INFO  | UNKNOWN_USER | com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - nGenDbPool - Started.
```

Comment: If you have not already done so I would raise a question with Brett on the github repo. He's very responsive to questions raised about Hikari

Comment: Please post your connection pool config.

Comment: @Jason HikariCP does not abandon/replace leaked connections; to do so would merely cover-up a bug (application or framework).  I do notice that your leakDetection threshold is pretty short (5sec) so you might get false leak reports.  Though v2.6.0 will now also log when a previously reported leaked connection is actually returned to the pool (un-leaked).  Because of the short threshold the ``findOne(UUID)`` method may merely be slow rather than an actual leak.  I do recommend upgrading to v2.6.0.  Please update your question with a leaked connection stacktrace here.  Thanks.

Comment: @brettw I am seeing the "unleaked" connection in the logs, and that's helpful.  We already changed that leaked setting to 5 minutes.  We also think we found the issue.   Seems like this line was causing the issue:           Map<String, List<FinancialRecord>> records = records.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(FinancialRecord::getFooId));.  We found some concurrent modification exceptions in the logs and the theory is that parallel stuff in Java operating on hibernate entities might be the issue.  w/o the parallel and concurrent, our issue seems to disappear (shrug)

Comment: @Jason  - Did you find any solution for your problem, i also have same problem